# Android - Control the flow of Loop by button presses

Tags: android

I have an activity class in my Android App, where after some data is handled, that data is sent to another method in another class which gives back an ArrayList. What I want to do is to iterate through that ArrayList and for every piece of text in it, I would like to update the TextView label in my interface. However this should be done whenever the user presses the 'Yes' button on screen. (i.e. whenever the user presses the 'Yes' button, the loop would progress to the next element of the ArrayList and its value updated in the TextView label). Here is what I have so far:

```
try {
        sentenceGenerator = new SentenceGenerator();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> states = stateGenerator
                .getPossibleStates(resultOutput, result, result);
        for (ArrayList<String> state : states) {
            viewPoint = state.get(0);
            subject = state.get(1);
            object = state.get(2);
            subjectInfo = new ObjectReference();
            if (resultOutput.equals("Sliema")) {
                Sliema sliema = new Sliema();
                subjectInfo = sliema.getInfo(viewPoint, object, subject);
            }
            try {
                s = sentenceGenerator.generateSentence("start", "middle",
                        "end", resultOutput, viewPoint, object, subject,
                        subjectInfo.type, subjectInfo.name,
                        subjectInfo.properties, false);
                instructionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instructionTextView);
                mHandler = new Handler();
                instructionTextView
                        .setText("Press 'Yes' to start Orientation procedure");
                Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);
                Button declineButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.declineButton);

                confirmButton
                        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mHandler.post(mUpdate);
                            }
                        });
                declineButton
                        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                //
                            }
                        });
                Log.d("INSTRUCTIONS", s);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }
```

and this is the update Handler:

```
private Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        instructionTextView.setText(s);
        // mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        confirmPressed = true;
        // i++;
    }
};
```

Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [SOLVED] - I took another approach and it worked. I was thinking naively there for a moment!

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding a `break;`in the `buttonclickListener` where you want to terminate the loop.

Comment: That won't work since the loop context seems to be lost in the buttonclickListener. Besides, I don't want to terminate the loop; I want it to hold until the button is pressed, then loads the next element and performs the sentenceGeneration for that string. Thanks anyway!